# How to log an element using protractor?

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to locate an element using protractor but I can't find it. To debug, I'd like to look at the element I did find and see which one it is. I have some code like this:

```
      myElement.all(by.cssContainingText('.name', 'value')).then(function (elems) {
    console.log(elems.length); <--- this line logs "2"
    console.log(elems[1]); <--- this line logs "{ ptor_: ...."
    elems[1].getInnerHtml().then(function(html){
        console.log(html); <--- never gets here
    }); });
```

How can I see what elements the all() method found?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's the best/most concise way, but you should be able to use `map` to loop over the elements, and use `getOuterHtml()` on each to access the HTML

```
myElement.all(by.cssContainingText('.name', 'value')).map(function(el) {
  return el.getOuterHtml();
}).then(function(html) {
  console.log(html);
});
```

Comment: The problem is that getInnerHtml()/getOuterHtml() does not actually return HTML. I always get "{ ptor_: ....".

For example, if I just do `var e = element(by.css('some-class')); console.log(e.getOuterHtml()/e.getInnerHtml())`, I don't get html in the output. How do I get the HTML instead of the protractor object?

Comment: @bea `getOuterHtml` does return a promise, so `console.log` of that wouldn't be helpful. However my answer shows how to log what it resolves to, which is a string of HTML.